# How do I import a folder with several .cpp source files, each with a main() definition, into an Eclipse project?

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows-10

I'm trying to compile the source files from the exercise download provided by Lynda's *C++ Essential Training*. The files are in the folders of a higher-level folder:

Some made up examples to show the folder structure:

> Cpp_essential_training\Chapter1\bread.cpp
>   Cpp_essential_training\Chapter2\potato.cpp
>   ...

Each of these source files has a `main()` function.

When I try to create a `C++ project` and then right click on it in the `Project Explorer` to import the exercise files as a `File System`, the `Console` gives me **errors of duplicate main functions** (because it assumes a single project with a single entry point).

When I try to create a `Folder` and then right click on it in the `Project Explorer` to import the exercise files as a `File System`, the IDE UI **greys out the build button** (because it assumes that I'm looking at generic text files).

How can I compile the exercise files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, every file is should be a project.
Do not make a project with all of the files
You can make a header and change the main functions. And insert the signatures in the header. And create another CPP file and write a new main and call functions in that.

Comment: Yes, I'll create a "working" C++ project, and copy the source files one-at-a-time from the imported File System in a Folder into the working project each time I look at a new exercise file. Thanks